# csv-writer npm default values

Tags: node.js, csv, npm

I am using csv-writer npm to write my objects into csv files. I need a way to add a default value in case a key don't exists in the object. Anyone had this need before?

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: 'path/to/file.csv',
    header: [
        {id: 'name', title: 'NAME'},
        {id: 'lang', title: 'LANGUAGE'}
    ]
});

const records = [
    {name: 'Bob',  lang: 'French, English'},
    {name: 'Mary', lang: 'English'},
    {name:'Foo'}

];

csvWriter.writeRecords(records)       // returns a promise
    .then(() => {
        console.log('...Done');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv-writer` writes an empty string for a field value if the field is missing. If you want to provide default values for fields, you can do something like below. Here, `English` will be given if `lang` is not specified.

```js
const defaultValues = {lang: 'English'}
const finalRecords = records.map(record => Object.assign({}, defaultValues, record))

csvWriter.writeRecords(finalRecords)
```